# A sequence converges to $x$ if and only if every subsequence converges to $x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a proposition on the book [Elementary Classical Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716721058) which states the following:

Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R$ and let x $\in \Bbb R$. Then $x_n \to x$ iff every subsequence of $x_n$ converges to $x$.

Could you please help me on the proof of this? I can't see any way to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove two directions.

1. When $x_n \rightarrow x$, can you use the limit definition to show that every subsequence must also converge to $x$? The limit definition, just to recall, is that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $|x_n - x|< \epsilon$ for all $n$ exceeding some $N$ depending only on $\epsilon$.
2. If $x_n$ does *not* converge to $x$, can you see why at least one subsequence does not converge to $x$?

If you have any further questions feel free to comment.

Comment: I have troubles on such proofs because I tend to think on examples when question is this. I think of some subsequences that converge to x, then I got lost trying to generalize proof. Is this valid way to approach such question?